# Determine if a generic param is a Nullable type

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, nullable

I have the following VB.NET function, for example:

```
Public Function MyFunction (Of TData) (ByVal InParam As Integer) As TData

End Sub
```

How do I, in a function, determine if `TData` is a NULLable Type?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One way is:

```
If Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(GetType(TData)) <> Nothing
```

... at least, the C# is:

```
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TData)) != null)
```

That's assuming you're asking whether it's a nullable value type. If you're asking whether it's a nullable value type *or a class* then the C# version would be:

```
if (default(TData) == null)
```

but I'm not sure whether a simple VB translation would work there, as "Nothing" is slightly different in VB.

Comment: The `<>` in your code should be `IsNot`. As you suspected, he `default` trick doesn’t work in VB since `Default(T)` doesn’t exist and is replaced by just `Nothing`, which is *always* the default value (for value types, it takes on the type’s default value).

Comment: It worked. ty. I'll accept after the appropriate min time elapses.

Comment: I'm sure this does work.  But does typeof(T) perform boxing?  If so, the results are unreliable.  I'm not sure if it does or not, but I'd like to know, and haven't found the answer online easily.

Comment: @Suamere: I don't know what you mean - `typeof(T)` always resolves to a `Type`, not a value of that type... what would be boxed?

Comment: @JonSkeet I was thinking in terms of variables, which T is obviously not.  But if T were, it would be boxed as an object and lose information.  Obviously that isn't the case since typeof is an expression and not a function, and T is a type parameter and not a variable.  Nevermind :)

Answer (score 7):

VB.net:

```
Dim hasNullableParameter As Boolean = _
        obj.GetType.IsGenericType _
        AndAlso _
        obj.GetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition = GetType(Nullable(Of ))
```

C#:

```
bool hasNullableParameter = 
        obj.GetType().IsGenericType && 
        obj.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
```

Comment: You can compare types via `=`, no `Equals` needed since `Type` instances are unique for each type.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the code given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426949/how-can-i-use-reflection-to-return-all-classes-subclassing-from-a-generic-withou/6427201#6427201), add an extension

```
public static bool IsNullable(this Type type) {
    Contract.Requires(type != null);
    return type.IsDerivedFromOpenGenericType(typeof(Nullable<>));
}
```

and say

```
bool nullable = typeof(TData).IsNullable();
```

Comment: This is the proper approach. Using Nullable.GetUnderlyingType is for when you KNOW its Nullable, IsDerivedFromOpenGenericType(typeof(Nullable<>)) is for ascertaining the lineage of a type.

Comment: Follow the link in the answer above to see IsDerivedFromOpenGenericType.