# Why can't I use ApplyConfiguration() to add my audit log table (Audit.NET can't find it)?

Tags: entity-framework-core, audit.net

I have an existing application that is built on Entity Framework Core 2.2.x. It is using `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration()` to associate entities with the data model dynamically. This works for all of the current entities and even my new AuditLog entity as far as the rest of the application is concerned.

However, when I configure Audit.NET's entity framework core provider to log into AuditLog, the data provider cannot write to the database:

> The entity type 'AuditLog' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

I have scoured the internet for solutions to that error, and found that adding this line to my code will cause Audit.NET to find my AuditLog:

`modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>().ToTable("AuditLog", "Audit");`

**My code:**

```cs
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Type[] maps = EntityFrameworkReflectionMapping.Get(EntityTypeConfiguration(), BoundAssemblies);

            foreach (object instance in maps.Select(Activator.CreateInstance))
                modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration((dynamic)instance);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>().ToTable("AuditLog", "Audit");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

*Why do I need to add the entity explicitly, when the rest of the system works as-is?*

Additionally, the changes are being detected by Audit.NET through entities which are not explicitly added. So the problem seems to be with Audit.NET's entity framework data provider, or how I'm using it.

I would expect that the data provider would respect the `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration()` approach to associating entities.

Comment: Does your `DbContext` has a `DbSet<AuditLog>` public property? Just guessing it could be because you don't have such property for `AuditLog`, but you do for the other tables that works.

Comment: Is the `AuditLog` defined on the same assembly as the other entities? Also have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388052/122195) answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could be causing the exception, but looks like EF is not being able to detect the entity-table relation for your `AuditLog`.

Look for a wrong connection string, maybe your `AuditLog` being defined on a different assembly than other entities.

Also try adding the `AuditLog` entity class within a db set as a property on your `DbContext`, for example:

```
public class MyContext : AuditDbContext
{
    //...
    public DbSet<ModelName> ModelName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: AuditLog is defined in a separate project from the entity that is being audited. Is that significant? Also, when I add DbSet<AuditLog> to the DbContext object, I then get this when it tries to log:  `Invalid object name 'AuditLog'.`

Comment: Yes I guess that's the problem. Check [this](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-register-model-builder-without-having-to-manually-add-them-one-by-one) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104651/122195)