# How to check if a generic type parameter is nullable?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if a generic param is a Nullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181494/determine-if-a-generic-param-is-a-nullable-type)

I'm trying to determine if a type parameter is Nullable.

```
    public T Get<T>(int index)
    {
        var none=default(T);
        var t = typeof(T);
        BaseVariable v = this[index].Var;
        if (T is Nullable) //compiler error
        {
            if (v == ... )
            {
                return none;
            }
        }
        //....
    }
```

How do I do this? I've tried doing `t == typeof(Nullable)` but that always resulted in false.

What I want to happen is for `foo.Get<bool?>(1)` to null at times.

Comment: This is a dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181494/determine-if-a-generic-param-is-a-nullable-type

Comment: @Nix that's in VB, so maybe borderline not a dupe. We'll see

Comment: The solutions are in C# and VB

Answer (score 61):

You can use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx):

```
var t = typeof(T);
// ...
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null)
{
    // T is a Nullable<>
}
```

Comment: This is not working in my version of .NET Core 3.1 with C#8.0

Comment: Works in net5.0/c#9, fwiw