# How to check type of unboxing nullable type with value = null?

Tags: c#-4.0, nullable, unboxing

Look at this method:

```
Dictionary<string,object> ViewModelParams = new Dictionary<string,object>();

AddParam(string paramKey,value)
{
    viewModelParams.Add(paramKey,value);
}

T GetParam<T>(string paramKey)
{
    if(viewModelParams[paramKey] is T)
        return (T)viewModelParams[paramKey];
    else
        throw exception...
}
```

For **Nullable** types the expression `if(viewModelParams[paramKey] is T)` , if value in dictionary was null, not worked properly, to clarify:

```
int? item=null;
AddParam("key",item);
GetParam<int?>("key")// throw exception because of 
                     // (viewModelParams[paramKey] is T) is false
```

I know concepts of boxing and unboxing for nullable type([Boxing Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), but i don't know which expression replaced with `if(viewModelParams[paramKey] is T)` for this scenario?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181494/determine-if-a-generic-param-is-a-nullable-type

Comment: @dotNET, this is't duplicate, i can't use compare with typeof or GetType().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the value is null, then it has no type and `is` will return false whatever you pass it. The only way the runtime could tell what type was in the dictionary value is if it wasn't null.

I think the best you could do here is a couple of overloads of your `GetParam` method:

```cs
T? GetParam<T>(string paramKey) where T : struct
{
    object value = viewModelParams[paramKey];
    if (value == null) return null;

    if(value is T)
        return (T?)value;
    else
        throw exception...
}

T GetParam<T>(string paramKey) where T : class
{
    object value = viewModelParams[paramKey];
    if (value == null) return null;

    if(value is T)
        return (T)value;
    else
        throw exception...
}
```

I've taken a couple of liberties here:

1. I've changed the signature such that when you request value type `T` you actually get `T?`. In your example you'd call `GetParam<int>` rather than `GetParam<int?>`.
2. If the value in the dictionary is null, I'm returning null, rather than throwing an exception. This is a change in behaviour, even if your `T` is a reference type. I think this is the behaviour you really wanted, as you were demonstrating attempting to store an `int?`.

Of course, you have probably worked around this issue now, ten years after you asked the question!