# CSharp Enumerate through nullable Enums

Tags: c#, enums

One piece of code is worth a thousand words...

```
public enum enTest { a, b, c }

public void PrintEnum<T>()
{
    foreach (var E in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    Debug.WriteLine(E.ToString());
}

PrintEnum<enTest>();
PrintEnum<enTest?>();    // This will cause failure in Enum.GetValues()
```

The above is simplified from a larger problem to illustrate the failure.

Does anyone know how can I iterate through (or get all the values inside) when someone passing me a Nullable Enum?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [Nullable.GetUnderLyingType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) help?

Comment: "One piece of code is worth a thousand words..." - but showing the error would help a lot too... along with using conventional names in your sample.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5181559/1466456

Comment: There is a bit of a misconception that you have "a nullable int" or "a nullable enum". You don't really, what you have is a type that can hold an int, or hold an enum, and also have the concept of null, but this type is neither an int nor an enum, it's a nullable value holding an int or an enum. There is compiler magic in the compilers to handle this and lift/promote the nullable types value out of the nullable value in expressions. So basically, nobody is passing you a nullable enum, they're passing you a `Nullable<T>` which is not an enum, but T is an enum. As such, you need to get the T.

Comment: You should really constrain the type `T` as much as possible to prevent passing in anything that's not an `enum`. (e.g. `where T : struct, IConvertible`)

Comment: As @germi mentioned, using nullable.GetUnderlyingType would give you back the required type, and since it gives back null if not a nullable, you could simply coalesce to keep it safe for normal usage: `Enum.GetValues(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T)))`

Comment: @Me.Name Didn't know about `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`, nice! Thanks!

Comment: A side-question would be if the method is passed a `Nullable<T>` holding an enum, should the method also print "null" as a legal value?

Comment: @DavidF - it doesn't look like you can, a, constrain a type to an enum, b, constrain a type to a type or it's nullable version.

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars Assuming you meant me and not a fictional DavidF? I know you can't constrain to an `enum` which is why I suggested `struct, IConvertible`.

Comment: @DavidG - yes I did :). Oh I see yes, I hadn't appreciated that.

Comment: @Lasse - yes, in fact my task is to create a selection list when passed in an enum by the caller. So if they are passing me a nullable enum, I will have to create a list with -none- as an option. It was not shown in the question for simplicity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```
public static void PrintEnum<T>()
        {
            Type t = typeof (T);
            if (t.IsGenericType)
            {
                //Assume it's a nullable enum
                t = typeof (T).GenericTypeArguments[0];
            }

            foreach (var E in Enum.GetValues(t))
                Console.WriteLine(E.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Improvement: `t = t.Generic....` and also se DavidG's comment on the question, makes it even simpler.

Comment: Me.Name's Enum.GetValues(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T)) is much better.